# c++ win32 how to rename a folder/directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

the question is pretty much self explained.
i looked up msdn and i couldn't find any API function for the purpose of renaming a folder 
is there a way to do so like **MoveFile()**  for files ?

Comment: "The MoveFile function will move (rename) either a file **or a directory**". See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks i didn't knew that i'll try with a non empty folder

Comment: As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx) says: "The MoveFile function will move (rename) either a file **or a directory (including its children)** either in the same directory or across directories. **The one caveat is that the MoveFile function will fail on directory moves when the destination is on a different volume.**"

Answer (score 1):

The path of least resistance might be to use rename() [[EXAMPLE]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/)

(Although, I do realize that this is a C function, not C++.)

Comment: What's worse, it doesn't cope with Unicode path names.